Shower knob fell off
The shower knob in my shower has fallen off but I don't know how to fix it. It looks like there are no interlocking holes and looks like an adhesive needs to be reapplied?



I'd call that the shower handle?  Is there a screw (or space for a screw) in the handle or a little cap that can be removed (in the handle) where a screw could go?

The square casting in the handle, ( red line) indicated there is a set screw that holds the handle on.
Look at the bottom, ( blue line).  That is where the set screw should go.

The hole for the screw may be clogged. It may be corroded. If so, it needs cleaned out.  If you are lucky it will be open and you can see the head of the screw, so you know what tool is needed to turn it to reattach the handle.
If there is just a hole you can see through , you lost the screw and need to find one that fits.  Visiting the helpful people at the plumbing supply store is your best bet.
